# How to further optimize filebeat/elasticsearch performance?

Tags: elasticsearch, optimization, filebeat

I'm ingesting very high volume of Netflow traffic to Filebeat v7.14, which then writes to Elasticsearch. I'm trying to optimize the performance, as I suspect that Filebeat/Elasticsearch is not ingesting everything. Both Filebeat and Elasticsearch run on the same server with total of 120GB RAM (64GB was ringfenced for ES).

I have modified the following settings in `filebeat.yml`, following the suggestions [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-tune-elastic-beats-performance-a-practical-example-with-batch-size-worker-count-and-more). These changes increased the number of events I see on Kibana from ~150K every 2 minutes to 150K every minute.

```
max_bulk_size: 1000    # Increasing further does not improve performance
worker: 4              # Increasing further does not improve performance
queue.mem.events: 12000
queue.mem.flush.min_events: 1000
```

If I look at the monitoring stats in filebeat's log, the percentage of dropped packets has decreased from about 50% before the modifications to 20% now.

```
"filebeat": {
    "input": {
        "netflow": {
            "flows": XXX,
            "packets": {
                "dropped": YYY,
                "received": ZZZ
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like no matter what I do (I've also tried to change ES's index `refresh_interval` to 30s, removed `_id` in the ingest pipeline so as to auto generate id), the max indexing rate and event rate is 150K per minute. If I just run filebeat and output to console without writing to ES (as suggested [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/file-beat-performance-how-to-check-if-file-beat-is-keeping-up-while-reading-files/102899/4)) using `pv`, the output I see is something like

```
[ 0 /s ] [...]
[ 932 /s ] [...]
[ 27.9k /s ] [...]
[ 26.8k /s ] [...]
[ 25.4k /s ] [...]
[ 26.4k /s ] [...]
[ 28.3k /s ] [...]
[ 16.7k /s ] [...]
[ 0 /s ] [...]
[ 0 /s ] [...]
[ 0 /s ] [...]
```

There will be a few seconds of non-zero events per second (summing to ~150k), and then zero until the next minute, and the cycle repeats itself. Is this an indication of a bottleneck with Filebeat? I don't think it's the traffic itself, because it is continuous and with high volume.

What else can I do with either Filebeat or ES to further tune the performance, preferably without dropping packets?

Comment: Hi mate, great job. I believe you need to make sure as to where the bottleneck is before trying anything. Check with Elasticsearch for rejected tasks, high cpu usage , high memory... here is a great doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fix-common-cluster-issues.html

Comment: Wow, that is a great resource, I'll be sure to go through it to see if there's any of the problems in my ES. Thanks!

Comment: I looked at the ES doc, but it doesn't seem like I'm having the issues mentioned in it. Plus, from my filebeat output to console testing without ES, I'm getting the same performance.